# Rails 3 "Application Error" when deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have pushed my Rails 3 app to Heroku but when I attempt to open it in the browser I get an "Application Error."

Running 'heroku logs' returns the following:

```
2014-05-12T17:19:12.592829+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"
method=GET path=/ host=mycfi.herokuapp.com request_id=a486e0ad-450e-4fa0-8546-
33e9d76e171d fwd="208.191.153.66" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

2014-05-12T17:19:13.127416+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"
method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=mycfi.herokuapp.com request_id=ba155c24-eadd-407c-
abf1-0e805fa17f82 fwd="208.191.153.66" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Running 'heroku run bundle exec rails console" returns the following:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for
these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your
Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and
config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this:
http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from
<top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)

DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for
these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your
Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and 
config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this:
http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from
<top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)

/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport- 
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': 
/app/app/controllers/stripe_events_controller.rb:27: syntax error, unexpected 
keyword_end (SyntaxError)

/app/app/controllers/stripe_events_controller.rb:46: syntax error, unexpected $end,
expecting keyword_end

    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

You'd think there would be an obvious 'end' somewhere that is causing this error but I am certain that this is not the case.  The lines of code that the error is referring to has worked before, so I am not sure what happened.

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Edit 1:  Here is referred to code from my stripe_events_controller.  Notice the comma that I accidentally left in (right before the comment).  Geez!

```
def parse_and_validate_event
  @event = StripeEvent.new(event_id: params[:id], event_type: params[:type])

  unless @event.save    # attempts to save to db
    if @event.valid?    # checks to see if unique
  render nothing: true, status: 400 # valid event, try again later
else
  render nothing: true, # invalid event, move along
end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clear:

```
/app/app/controllers/stripe_events_controller.rb:46: syntax error, unexpected $end,
expecting keyword_end
```

Perhaps your code has not been committed to source control and pushed? This is not an error on Heroku.

Comment: Yep.  Left in a comma that didn't need to be there.  Thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :)